# Datedropper Issue with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am facing an error with datedropper

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeClass' of undefined
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (datedropper.js:1805)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I have used to same code which I have on the live server but in local server giving the error.

Html Code

```
<input data-large-default="true" data-large-mode="true" data-format="Y-m-d" placeholder="Y-m-d" type="text" class="qInput" id="qFormsDate" required>
```

JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        //$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $('#qFormsDate').dateDropper();
    });
```

I have used the

> jQuery 3.3.1 and 
>   jQuery-migrate

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Show your Javascript code and HTML !

Comment: Thanks for your comment i have sort this out..